# Can't able to create sales invoice in ERP Next with REST

Tags: python, rest, erpnext, frappe

I want to create invoice through REST. I sent all the required parameters but it's showing me "The resource you are looking for is not available".

The endpoint I have used "http://mydomain.amazonaws.com/api/resource/Sales Invoice". Kindly help me. Sorry for my poor English.

```
{
  "naming_series": "SINV-ST",
  "docstatus":1,
  "customer": "Ayan Bera",
  "customer_name": "Ayan Bera",
  "is_pos": "1",
  "company": "Succeed Technologies",
  "posting_date": "2017-12-23",
  "due_date": "2017-12-23",
  "currency": "INR",
  "selling_price_list": "Standard Selling",
  "price_list_currency": "INR",
  "discount_amount": 0,
  "apply_discount_on": "Grand Total",
  "cash_bank_account": "Cash - ST",
  "write_off_amount": 0,
  "debit_to": "Accounts Receivable - ST",
  "remarks": "via b2b mobile app",
  "customer_group": "Individual",
  "submit_on_creation": 1,
  "against_income_account": "Accounts Receivable - ST",
  "paid_amount": 360,
  "mode_of_payment": "Cash",
  "is_opening": "No",
  "status": "Paid",
  "amount_received": "360",
  "amount_returned": "0.0",
  "update_stock": 1,
  "items": [{
  "item_code": "f-r-02",
  "item_name": "Orange",
  "qty": "2",
  "rate": "80.0",
  "expense_account": "Accounts Receivable - ST",
  "cost_center": "Main - ST",
  "warehouse": "All Warehouses - ST",
  "parenttype": "SalesInvoice",
  "parentfield": "items"
  }, {
  "cost_center": "Main - ST",
  "qty": "2",
  "warehouse": "All Warehouses - ST",
  "item_code": "f-r-01",
  "item_name": "Orange Big",
  "rate": "100.0",
  "expense_account": "Accounts Receivable - ST",
  "parenttype": "Sales Invoice",
  "parentfield": "items",
  "base_paid_amount": 360
  }],
  "payments": [{
        "mode_of_payment": "Cash",
        "amount": 360,
        "account": "Cash - ST",
        "base_amount": 360
  }]
 }
```

Comment: Please post the full response with error code

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this happens, it means that one of the dependencies of your DocType is misnamed.

The only way to find out is to actually try to GET each one, until you find the one that does not exist (for whatever reason).

```
  "naming_series": "SINV-ST",
  "customer": "Ayan Bera",
  "company": "Succeed Technologies",
  "currency": "INR",
  "selling_price_list": "Standard Selling",
  "cash_bank_account": "Cash - ST",
  "customer_group": "Individual",
  "mode_of_payment": "Cash",
  "item_code": "f-r-02",
  "item_code": "f-r-01",
  "cost_center": "Main - ST",
  "warehouse": "All Warehouses - ST",
  "expense_account": "Accounts Receivable - ST",
  "mode_of_payment": "Cash",
```

Any one of the above could be missing, but your item codes look unusual to me.  I'd check them first.

I have Postman and use it to pretest all the API calls I expect to use in my app. I have built up a library of them, which makes it quick and easy to test each item in a list of dependencies as above.